# initWithContentsOfURL is nil even with NSAppTransportSecurity set to NSAllowsArbitraryLoads

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsapptransportsecurity

This line of code gives me an NSData object with nil contents:

```
NSData *jsonData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

If I look at `urlString` (which uses `http` rather than `https`) in Xcode it's giving me a URL which, in a browser, gives me valid JSON.

For testing I have set this in the plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

However, I am still getting an NSData object with nil contents. If it helps it was all working before the `NSAppTransportSecurity` requirement which is why I tried setting `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`.

Any suggestions what else I can try?

==== UPDATE

```
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSData *jsonData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] options:nil error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
```

gives `(null)` in the console.

Comment: Use `-[NSData initWithContentsOfURL:options:error:]` to find out why it's failing.

Comment: @Avi The value for `error` is nil. e.g. see updated code above.

Comment: While it's unlikely to get a system error that has a null `localizedDescription`, try logging the error object itself.

Comment: @Avi that returns null too.

Comment: Can you share the URL?  At the moment, I am stumped.

Comment: The URL isn't an issue. I get an NSData object with valid content with iOS 8.4 but not iOS 9.2. Clearly `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` is being ignored. Why?